# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while using the NormalDistribution class of org.apache.math3

Tags: eclipse, noclassdeffounderror, apache-commons, normal-distribution

I am receiving the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error while using the NormalDistribution class of org.apache.math3

Attaching the statement where i am getting the error below.

```
    org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution dis = new org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution(0,1);
```

I am trying to use the "normalDistribution" class of org.apache.math3 but getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
The complete code is provided below:

```
package com.src;
import org.apache.commons.math4.core.jdkmath.*;
import org.apache.commons.math4.legacy.distribution.*;
import org.apache.commons.math4.legacy.distribution.fitting.*;
public class Ztest {
  private boolean srs;
  private boolean independent;
  private boolean largeCounts;
  private double significanceLevel;
  private double testStatistic;
  private double pValue;
  private double nullProportion;
  private CategoricalDataSet data;
  public Ztest(boolean random, boolean percent, boolean big, double alpha, CategoricalDataSet d, double Ho, String direction) {
      srs = random;
      independent = percent;
      largeCounts = big;
      significanceLevel = alpha;
      nullProportion = Ho;
      data = d;
      testStatistic = (data.getProportion() - nullProportion)/data.standardError();
      org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution dis = new org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution(0,1);
      if(direction.equals("less than")) {
          pValue = dis.cumulativeProbability(testStatistic);
      }
      else if(direction.equals("greater than")) {
          pValue = dis.cumulativeProbability( -1.0 * testStatistic);
      }
      else {
          if(testStatistic > nullProportion) {
              pValue = 2.0 * dis.cumulativeProbability( -1.0 * testStatistic);
          }
          else {
              pValue = 2.0 * dis.cumulativeProbability(testStatistic);
          }
      }
  }
  public String summary() {
      String message;
      if(pValue < significanceLevel) {
          message = "Since the Pvalue is less than the signficance level, we have sufficient evidence to reject the null hypothesis (H0).";
      }
      else {
          message = "Since the Pvalue is greater than the significance level, we have insufficient evidence to reject the null hypthesis.";
      }
      return message;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are mixing o.a.c.math3 and o.a.c.math4. Without being able to try out things now, i assume you're adding version 4, but look for code from version 3?

Comment: [Please do not ask two questions about the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76518248/6505250).